# ValueError when using split() with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, mapreduce, delimiter, valueerror

**Question:**
I would like to know how to use split() in python, for text with two or more delimiters in it. I get error when I run my code. The code, error, and sample data are provided below.

**Code:**

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep


class LeagueCount(MRJob):
    def steps(self):
        return [
            MRStep(
                mapper=self.mapper_get_league,
                reducer=self.reducer_count_league
            )
        ]

    def mapper_get_conference(self, _, line):
        (Players, Team,League, year) = line.split('|')
        yield League, 1

    def reducer_count_league(self, key, values):
        yield key, sum(values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LeagueCount.run()
```

**Observed Error:**
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)

**Sample Data:**
player1, player2, player3|Chelsea|Premiership|2014
player1, player2, player3|Arsenal|Premership|2018
player1, player2, player3|Spurs|Premership|2015
player1, player2, player3|Chelsea|Premership|2016

Comment: You need to edit the post to do the following:
1) Provide proper indents for the code.
2) give us a sample of what the line contains so that we can understand why this error is thrown (as in why it is returning more than 4 elements).
3) Provide us clear expected output of what your are trying to achieve.
If you provide these details we can help you out better. As of now the question is underspecified.

Comment: @the23Effect Thanks for your response, code added with sample data.

Comment: Thanks for providing the details. There were some format errors in the post I have edited them.

Comment: @the23Effect I have updated the post, when I use this code above with only one player it works, am able to get each unique league and its count. However, by adding more players using comma separations it pops up this error. Please let me know your thoughts, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Update 1:** (After you changed data and code):

In your code you have set, `mapper=self.mapper_get_league,` but the function is named as `mapper_get_conference()`. I changed that and ran the code with exact same data and it works in my system. Below is the output I got.

**Partial output:**

```
Running step 1 of 1...  
"Premership"    3  
"Premiership"   1
```

**Note:**

- Make sure you don't have empty lines at the end of data file, that will throw, **`ValueError: not enough values to unpack(expected 4, got 1)`**. This is because mapper will try to read an empty line which will have no characters, so it will contain None and it is trying to assign that to 4 variables.
- Make sure each entry(line) in the data is in a new line, as a line of input is till the new line. If you don't have a newline and two rows of data are in one line then split() will produce more values than intended and throw **`ValueError: too many values to unpack(expected 4)`**.

So am guessing the issue is with the data.